# Waves survival balance

Tags: balance, waves

I'm trying to create another Vampire Survivors clone and realize that the hardest part isn't the graphics or the code, but the balance. How do similar successful games achieve good balance, considering the multitude of characters, spells, and enemy counts? How to ensure that replayability with different sets is balanced and not too difficult or too easy?

I'm trying to implement a simulation of playthroughs (100 times in a 100 times accelerated mode). But it still requires a huge number of combinations.

Comment: The hardest thing when trying to tune the balancing of a game is defining what you mean by "good balance". What is "too easy" or "too difficult" and what does it mean to "ensure replayability" within the context of your game mechanics and creative goals? Once you can identify concrete measures for those traits, designing formulas or tests to ensure they're met is a lot easier. Re: simulating playthroughs with different combinations, [you might find this GDC talk "Balancing Nightmares" useful](https://gdcvault.com/play/1026033/Balancing-Nightmares-An-AI-Approach) — they use a genetic algorithm.